# Use localStorage variable inside WHERE clause with SharePointPlus

Tags: sharepoint, local-storage

I use SharePointPlus and I'm trying to use localStorage variable in the WHERE clause. Below my code:

```
$SP().list('Pracownicy').get({
  fields:"SID,Dost_x0119_py,Dost_x0119_py_Zam,Dzia_x0142_,Rola",
  where:"SID = localStorage.getItem('sid')"
  ....
```

This variable is a string. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is it possible to use such variable there? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old message, but the reason is that `localStorage.getItem('sid')` is inside the string, so it's not resolved.

Solution :

```
$SP().list('Pracownicy').get({
  fields:"SID,Dost_x0119_py,Dost_x0119_py_Zam,Dzia_x0142_,Rola",
  where:"SID = "+localStorage.getItem('sid')
```